# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Listings#index error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, coffeescript

I'm receiving this **ExecJS error message when I open my localhost**, I don't know why, some help would be amazing.

### I got this on my localhost

Showing /.../conektec/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:16: unexpected newline
  (in /.../conektec/app/assets/javascripts/orders.js.coffee)

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:2:73: unmatched )
  (in /Users/hbendev/startups/conektec/conektec/app/assets/javascripts/orders.js.coffee)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Conektec</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %> 
    8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    9:   <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
```

### Here is my orders.js.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
  $('#new_order').submit ->
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
    Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
    false

handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
  if status == 200
    alert(response.id)
  else
    alert(response.error.message)
```

### Here's my application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Conektec</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %> 
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
</head>

<body>

<%= render 'layouts/header' %>

<div class="container">

    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? "success" : "danger" %> alert-dismissable">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I already tried deleting my *turbolinks*, adding the *rubyracer* gem, I have *nodejs* installed, I don't know where's the error.

I'm using:
*OS X Mavericks*
*Ruby 2.0.0*
*Rails 4.1.1*

**What's wrong?** ***Thanks***.

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: And what do you think `Stripe.setPublishableKey($)('meta[name="stripe-key"]')` will do?

Comment: Oh I just realised was the indentation, true. I fix it.
Now the error is gonne, but got another problem, when I hit the Submit button (see the coffeescript code) I don't receive any Pop-Up message in my browser (Chrome), the only action is the .attr('disabled', true) that disables the button after I click on it.

I edit the code of `Stripe.setPublishableKey($)('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))` to: `Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))`, same error, doesn't appear the alert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is in your CoffeeScript syntax (line 6, column 16, as it states in the error):

```
# The lack of indentation after the setupForm line is incorrect
payment =
  setupForm: ->
  $('#new_order').submit ->
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
    Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
    false

# Make it this
payment = 
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
      false
```

Edit: it's worth noting that whenever there is an ExecJS error, it's usually a pretty good sign that there's an issue with your CoffeeScript syntax (thus causing a compilation error). It's not an actual JavaScript error in this case.'

To fix the OTHER issue you're having, since I can't comment, you need to indent your `handleStripeResponse` function so that it is nested underneath your payment object:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
      false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

I'm not sure how you have these errors, considered they are copied directly from the Railscasts episode; try to be very careful about your indentation with CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thanks to the SO hall monitors for once again shutting down a useful question so they can be the smartest person in the room.

Comment: @user1130176 Not sure what you mean—I'm not the one who closed this question. I answered it almost 3 years ago.

Comment: I was just venting, I absolutely hate it when people on SO close questions as off topic when they're providing value to other people. It's just childish priggishness and doesn't serve anyone.