# ExecJS::RuntimeError while implementing Angular Js in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Angular Js in Rails Project, I am following this tutorial http://angular-rails.com/bootstrap.html, after going through all of the steps I am getting this error:

[image]

I have searched the web about this but didn't get enough info, somewhere it was mentioned that it is due to node.js, but I have already installed node.js on my system.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635975).

problem was with my coffee script, there was a missing parenthesis,

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("RecipesController", [ '$scope',
  ($scope)->
]
```

"**)**" was missing in the above script.

thanks for the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635975).

Answer (score -2):

Add `gem 'therubyracer'`

then, execute `bundle install`

Comment: still same issue :(

Comment: try sudo apt-get install nodejs